# Heat Kernel on Sphere for Vector Laplacian

Tags: specific-reference, differential-geometry

Can somebody please provide me with a reference where the method of evaluating the heat kernel for spin-1 fields,i.e. vector laplacians on a 2-sphere is given? 
Please suggest some references accessible for physicists.

Comment: Hi @Emilio Pisanty: Concerning retagging: If you haven't done this already please read the wiki tags for the ref.req. and books tags. I believe the books tag is appropriate here, while the ref.req. tag is not.

Comment: "Heat kernel expansion: User's manual" [hep-th/0306138] is one of the canonical references accessible to physicists who want to learn about heat kernels.